# How to get a score over 9,000,000 on the ruins course?

Tags: new-pokemon-snap

Is there a secret score multiplier in Pokemon snap? I have a score in the 5 millions like the rest of the top players other than this one person.
With 15 Pokemon in ruins, it would take a score of over 8000 on all 72 pictures. Is this a cheat/ exploit?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://www.neoseeker.com/forums/103903/t2381392-ruins-9-000-000-score/) discussion thread (which was started around the same time your question), there is no feasible way to achieve that high of a score legitimately in the game. The only way to obtain that high of a score is to use a hacked console, or modded version of the game